# Qual a melhor maneira de se fazer uma função de um arquivo "Node" ser chamada no meu site HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, aplicação-desktop, electron

Estou fazendo um projeto de um *player de música simples* utilizando o ElectronJS.
Para isso estou usando uma biblioteca que reproduz arquivos MP3(play-sound), como posso chamar essa função dentro do meu HTML? Eu preciso criar outro arquivo apenas para reprodução de sons ou posso jogar essa função dentro do arquivo principal?

***CÓDIGO: index.js***

```
console.log('Main process working');

const electron = require('electron');
const app = electron.app;
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
const path = require('path');
const url = require('url');
const player = require('play-sound');

let win;

function createWindow(){
  win = new BrowserWindow({width: 300, height: 200, resizable: false, 
  minimizable: false, fullscreen: false, center: true});
  win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/app/public/index.html`);

  win.on('closed', () =>{
    win = null;
  });
}

app.on('ready', createWindow);
```

O código para tocar sons é:

```
var audio = player.play('nomedoarquivo.mp3', {/*efeitos*/}, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
});
```

E para parar:

```
audio.kill();
```

Como eu posso chamar esta função dentro do meu arquivo HTML?

Aceito sugestões de bibliotecas importantes para todos projetos!

Comment: Não querendo parecer "pedante", mesmo que a questão já tenha sido resolvida eu recomendo reformular seu titulo porque: um app Electron não pode ser definido como um site. Isso ajuda a comunidade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diferentemente de [NW.js](https://nwjs.io/) que compartilha o contexto do navegador e de node no mesmo processo o que permite executar pacotes **npm** e acessar API's do navegador no mesmo arquivo `.js`, Electron faz diferente, em Electron cada contexto é executado em um processo isolado, a maneira como node e o código de "front-end" se comunicam é através de mensagens.

**Mensagens**:

Tanto o código no processo principal como no processo de renderização utilizam uma instância de [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter) para trocar mensagens ... no processo principal utiliza-se o módule [ipcMan](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main) ou a propriedade **"webContents"** de **"BrowserWindow"**:

```
// use ipcMain no processo principal (sync/async) ----------------
const {ipcMain} = require('electron')
// ouvinte, resposta assíncrona
ipcMain.on('iniciar-player', (event, arg) => {
    // sua lógica aqui ...
    event.sender.send('player-reply', 'started-async')
})

// ouvinte, resposta síncrona
ipcMain.on('iniciar-player', (event, arg) => {
    // sua lógica aqui ...
    event.returnValue = 'started-sync'
})

// no processo de renderização (página web) ----------------------
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron')

// ouvinte assíncrono (ouvinte antes do envio)
ipcRenderer.on('player-reply', (event, arg) => {
    console.log(arg) // "started-async"
})
// enviar
ipcRenderer.send('iniciar-player', 'argumento-ou-configuração')

// ouvinte síncrono
let response = ipcRenderer.sendSync('iniciar-player', 'argumento-ou-configuração')
console.log(response) // "started-sync"
```

No processo principal execute a lógica de seu módulo. O próximo exemplo usa **"webContents"** no processo principal (assincronamente):

```
// no processo principal (async) ---------------------------------
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
let win = null

app.on('ready', () => {
    win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})
    win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/app/public/index.html`)
    // ouvinte
    win.webContents.on('iniciar-player', (/*parametros serializados em JSON por padrão*/) => {
        // sua lógica ...
        win.webContents.send('player-reply', 'started-async') // responda
    })
})

// no processo de renderização (página web) ----------------------
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron')

// ouvinte assíncrono (ouvinte antes do envio)
ipcRenderer.on('player-reply', (event, arg) => {
    console.log(arg) // "started-async"
})
// enviar
ipcRenderer.send('iniciar-player', 'argumento-ou-configuração')
```

Isto é o básico sobre troca de mensagens entre o código executado na página (render) e o processo principal (main).

---

> Nota: você pode ainda se abstrair destas mensagens usando o módulo **remote** caso deseje apenas acessar o módulo sem passar pelo processo principal

**Remote**:

Você pode acessar no processo de renderização um módulo ou arquivo (`.js`) em especifico através do módulo [remote](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/remote):

```
// no processo de renderização (página web)
const player = require('electron').remote.require('play-sound')

// abrir player
const audio = player.play('nomedoarquivo.mp3', {/*efeitos*/}, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
});

// simulando a iteração do usuário para encerrar o player
document.getElementById('btn-fechar-player').addEventListener('click', () => {
    audio.kill()
}, false)
```

Usar **remote** parece bem mais simples más, leia a documentação ... "algumas coisas" não são recomendadas fazer ao usar **remote**.

---

**Fontes**:

- [Electron API](https://electronjs.org/docs/api)

  - [ipcMain](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main)
  - [webContents](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents)
  - [remote](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/remote)